# Cross-Correlation (and finding Correlation error ) of two digital sequences.

Tags: correlation

In a IEEE paper, I saw a formula for WUInt(t<sub>i+1</sub>) as ,[image] Reference : 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6163385&contentType=Journals+%26+Magazines&queryText%3Dtraffic+aware+dynamic+mac

There I have two doubts.

1. How **cross-correlation of the two digital sequence is used to find the correlation-error.**
2. What is Weighting Average Algorithm by which µ(t<sub>i</sub>) is calculated.

In the Weighting Average Algorithm they are using a **constant weighting factor** but how to get the value.

**Info**: In that paper they said, the cross-correlation is used to smooth the output of weighting average algorithm. Also, its given that correlation error will be either +<sup>ve</sup> or -<sup>ve</sup>.